# Workflow; Appliccation to one Folder

Tags: workflow

How do I apply workflows to only one Folder in a Library?  When I create the one I want to use, it is activated for all documents within all folders in the library.

Comment: Why not put that folder in its own library? Folders [should](https://www.cloud2.co.uk/15-reasons-not-to-use-folders-in-sharepoint-and-3-reasons-why-you-could/) [be](http://www.meraksystems.com/company/newsevents/56-sharepoint-folder-vs-metadata) [avoided](http://sharepointmaven.com/12-reasons-folders-sharepoint-bad-idea/) in SharePoint anyhow.

Comment: Folders have their uses, saying they should be avoided is painting with a very broad brush

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Workflow could not be applied to a specific folder, but to verify if the item is located under a specific folder named GokieGary.

you could create a List Workflow and specify the following condition

```
CurrentItem:SourceURL ends with GokieGary
```

[image]